# Creating a reusable date formatter in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I've been struggling to create a reusable function that I can call on dates in my data. The goal is to take any date given, determine if it has just a date, or date and time, then return the data in the appropriate format.

I've been using moment to format things, but am not sure how to actually call this function on the data. I'm very new to React

Here is what I've got so far:

```
    import moment from "moment";
    
    const FormatDate = (dateObject) => {
      var dateMutant = dateObject;
      var dateMutated = "";
    
      function justDate() {
        //formats just a date
        dateMutated = moment.utc(dateMutant).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      }
    
      function dateTime() {
        //formats a date and time
        dateMutated = moment.utc(dateMutant).format("MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:a");
      }
      console.log(dateMutated);
      return dateMutated;
    };
    export default FormatDate
```

I am attempting to call it in a page like this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var testDate = '';
    if (allCommentsFetch) {
      setAllCommentsLoading(true);
      axios
        .get(`###API Hook##`)
        .then(response => {
          let comments = response.data;
          comments.forEach(commentfield => {
            if (commentfield != null) {
              commentfield['commentTimestamp'] = moment.utc(commentfield.commentTimestamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
              testDate = FormatDate(commentfield.commentTimestamp).justDate();
            } else {
              comments[commentfield] = 'N/A'
            }
          })
```

but am getting an error that Object(...)(...).justDate is not a function.

Comment: you are not calling the inner functions you're just declaring. also are those comments placed correctly ?

Comment: Ah, fixed that. Does react work similarly to other languages in that I could call from another file something like cleansedDate = FormatDate(dateData).justDate()? (assuming I import FormatDate at the top of my file.)

Comment: Yes you can create a folder like "utils" or "helpers" , then you can export the global functions from there. It's also good practice and looks organized.

Comment: Note that JS has been getting significant updates every year for quite a few years now, and moment.js is now a legacy solution for something that the modern JS date/time APIs are more appropriate for (even explicitly called out [by the moment.js folks](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/): you should not need moment.js anymore)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you; is date-fns the standard now?

Comment: @İlker, It appears that it won't let me call it in the way I think it should. I've updated the question with more information. Thanks already for the help and input.

Comment: @femmefunction justDate and dateTime functions are not properties of FormatDate. I think you confused it with Classes. I can't say how but you need to first if check if the dateObject has time in it. Then accordingly format the date. You don't need to define functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write it in a better and cleaner way, first of all, you have not to write your module names in PascalCase, `getFormattedName` will be a better choice! the second thing is that you are using var... avoid that.

the only thing you have to change in the `format` function is a format template... and as i see you have only two option (`justDate` and `dateTime`) in this case, so let's write it again:

```
const getFormattedDate = ({ dateObject, includeTime }) => {
  const dateFormat = includeTime ? 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:a' : 'MM-DD-YYYY';
  return moment.utc(dateObject).format(dateFormat);
};
```

and about the error you got: (`but am getting an error that Object(...)(...).justDate is not a function`) the problem is that you didn't return `justDate` from the `FormatDate` function.

Comment: This worked for me with some slight alteration, more with how it's going to be used. I already parse out the dates before passing them, so it's not a true date object.


`import moment from 'moment';

const getFormattedDate = (dateObject, includeTime) => {
  const dateFormat = includeTime ? 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a' : 'MM-DD-YYYY';
  return moment.utc(dateObject).format(dateFormat);
};

export default getFormattedDate;`